# vector referencing a class

Tags: java, class, vector, 2d-vector

Consider the following:

```
 class a
 {
  int p;
   a(int x)
    {
    p=x;
 }
 }

class b
{ vector<a> var;
   b(*type*a l)
    {
     new var;
     var(l);
     }
 }
```

basically, im trying to create a vector of a class ('a') and call it from another class. Few questions-

1) In class b, is the placement of the 'new var' correct? should I declare it outside the constructor when I define vector var or inside the constructor ? what do each of these cases mean.

2) in main, i want to declare a vector of class b as well. how would i do this?

does

```
Vector<b>  ex = new Vector<b> (100,5); sound right?
```

ie, 100 is the size and 5 is the amount by which it should be increased it it reaches full capacity?

Could I just not specify size and keep adding through addElement()?- would the vector type automatically increase its size?

3)Therefore, to access the ith element of b, and the jth element of the member variable 'var' of b,
how would i specify it?
 would this be right-?

```
 ex[i].var.get[j] ?
```

Im just starting out with all this, so bear with me. I am a real novice.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but -- you should really download a Java compiler (or better yet, an IDE such as Eclipse), buy a book on the language, and work your way through it.

Comment: 1) Learn to properly indent your code.  2) Learn by actually write something and compile, instead of just brainstorming.  Most of the question can be answered if you have actually go through some introductory material, and by reading the API a bit more careful.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm just starting out and willing to learn. I'm using an IDE, and every line keeps raising an error. I just started with Java and vectors yesterday, and I'm having problems trying to reference a class with a vector.. That's the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're referring to `java.util.Vector` don't use it unless you know what you're doing. Use `java.util.ArrayList` instead.

The following shows how to declare and initialize an ArrayList that is to contain objects of type `a`.

```
class b { 

    private ArrayList<a> var = new ArrayList<a>(); // declare & intialize like this

    b(a l) {
        var.add(l);
    }
}
```

An ArrayList of ArrayLists...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>> foo = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>>();

// initialize foo

foo.get(0).get(2);  // like foo[0][2] if foo were an array
```

Comment: Thank! but shouldn't it be var.add(l)?